# View not loading from Storyboard on InstantiateViewController() call

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to present a view controller in a Forms dependency service. But I keep getting a black screen. I can get it to work when I use Swift in Xcode, but not using Xamarin.

Controller outlets are not loading either. Strange thing is changes to `vc.View` do appear. It’s as though it’s creating a blank view and not actually loading from the storyboard.

My code is as follows:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("StoryboardView", null);
var controller = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("StoryboardViewVC");

var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
var vc = window.RootViewController;
while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
{
    vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
}

vc.PresentViewController(controller, true, null);
```

Adding a call to `LoadViewIfNeeded()` does not fix the issue.

I have double-checked that the storyboard and controller names match, which they do. I’ve searched for answers, but everything I’m finding revolves around not writing code to load the controller from the storyboard or nib.

Comment: Do you want "StoryboardViewVC" to be your RootViewController? If that´s the case: window.RootViewController = controller. Otherwise,
What´s the goal of the while loop? It looks disturbing to me. Did you try removing that?

Comment: @xleon No, I want to present the view controller modally. Doing so requires a controller to present from. As this is called from Xamarin.Forms via a dependency service and Forms, to my knowledge, does not expose the VC that a Page uses, I must get my hands a little dirty and find the most suitable VC myself, hence the while loop. Still, this does not explain why `controller` does not seem to be loading from the storyboard even before it's presented.

Answer (score 0):

```
var controller = (UIViewController)storyboard.InstantiateViewController("StoryboardViewVC");
```

use class you assigned to your view that may load your view.

Comment: Are you talking about casting the return value of the instant image method?